# Joining using a subquery or a join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. I need to join them using some join or sub query. The values of the column 'DWVertical Group' (of 2nd Table) should come from the 1st table. How should I implement this?

First Table

```
    Select Distinct
    case when exists (
    Select VerticalNameGroup 
    from CDB_Verticals 
    where VerticalNameGroup = DWVerticalGroup and ServiceLine='N'
    ) then DWVerticalGroup 
    else 'Others' 
    end as DWVertical 
    from dbo.dw_UtilizationPredictionReport
```

Second Table (The value of column 'DWVertical Group' should come from 1st table)

```
    Declare @Date Date = ( Select Max(RecordDate) from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport)


    SELECT 
        t1.RecordDate,
        t1.DWVerticalGroup,
        t1.OnOff,
        t1.LocationGrouping,
        t1.WFMGrade,
        t1.BHRS,
        t1.AHRS,
        t1.OffTFTE,
        t1.OffBFTE,
        COALESCE(t2.CTFTE, 0) CTFTE,
        COALESCE(t2.OverallFTE, 0) OverallFTE,
        COALESCE(t3.ATFTE,0) ATFTE,
        COALESCE(t3.SATFTE,0) SATFTE,
        COALESCE(t4.WCTFTE,0) WCTFTE,
        COALESCE(PAQ.COST,0) PAQCOST
    FROM
    (
        SELECT RecordDate, DWVerticalGroup , OnOff, LocationGrouping, WFMGrade,
            SUM(BilledHrs) BHRS, SUM(AvailableHrs) AHRS, SUM(TotalFTE) OffTFTE,
            SUM(BilledFTE) OffBFTE
        FROM dw_UtilizationPredictionReport 
        WHERE RecordDate=@Date AND OnOff = 'Offshore'
        GROUP BY
            DWVerticalGroup, OnOff, LocationGrouping, WFMGrade, RecordDate
    ) t1
```

Comment: Explain the relationship between the two tables

Comment: Create a table variable and store output of first query in this table variable. In second query, just use join on table variable. As per your business requirements, you need to be clear about join condition between these 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join to achieve this-

```
Declare @Date Date = ( Select Max(RecordDate) from dw_UtilizationPredictionReport)


SELECT 
    t1.RecordDate,
    case when t2.VerticalNameGroup is not null then t1.DWVerticalGroup else 'Others' end as DWVerticalGroup ,
    t1.OnOff,
    t1.LocationGrouping,
    t1.WFMGrade,
    t1.BHRS,
    t1.AHRS,
    t1.OffTFTE,
    t1.OffBFTE,
    COALESCE(t2.CTFTE, 0) CTFTE,
    COALESCE(t2.OverallFTE, 0) OverallFTE,
    COALESCE(t3.ATFTE,0) ATFTE,
    COALESCE(t3.SATFTE,0) SATFTE,
    COALESCE(t4.WCTFTE,0) WCTFTE,
    COALESCE(PAQ.COST,0) PAQCOST
FROM
(
    SELECT RecordDate, DWVerticalGroup , OnOff, LocationGrouping, WFMGrade,
        SUM(BilledHrs) BHRS, SUM(AvailableHrs) AHRS, SUM(TotalFTE) OffTFTE,
        SUM(BilledFTE) OffBFTE
    FROM dw_UtilizationPredictionReport 
    WHERE RecordDate=@Date AND OnOff = 'Offshore'
    GROUP BY
        DWVerticalGroup, OnOff, LocationGrouping, WFMGrade, RecordDate
) t1

left join CDB_Verticals as t2
on t2.VerticalNameGroup = t1.DWVerticalGroup and ServiceLine='N'
```